# Can Events Be Triggered from Within an ASP.NET Controller Class or Classes Called by the Controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, events, asp.net-web-api

I am working with an ASP.NET Core Web API project. The project already has it's API structure laid out and cannot easily be changed at this point. However, I received an unusual request from a customer who's asking if I could trigger a custom script or email whenever specific API endpoints are called by a client. I instantly thought of using events since I know you can use them to generate alerts from one object (class) that are handled by other objects. I started by adding an event to the helper class that gets called by the controller. Only specific action methods within the controller call this helper class to do things like save records to a database or make HTTP requests to other resources. The event I added uses the EventHandler delegate type. I created a custom class the inherits from EventArgs, following the recommendation from Microsoft. The problem I'm running into is that most of the methods I have in the helper class that are called by the controller are asynchronous. So, my question is, do ASP.NET Core Web API projects support triggering and handling events? If so, what would be the proper way to do it. Here is my controller code:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")
public class MyController : ControllerBase{
    //properties go here
    
    [HttpGet("/Records/{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get(int id){
        //Set variables and do other stuff here
        //Do something else here
        HelperClass serveRequest = new HelperClass();
        serveRequest.DoSomethingMethod(param1, param2, param3);
    }
}
```

As you can see above, the Get action method calls a method (DoSomethingMethod) from my helper class. The code for my helper class is below:

```
public class HelperClass{
    //class properties here
    
    public event EventHandler<CustomEventArgs> SomethingHappenedEvent;
    
    public HelperClass(){
        //instance initialization code
    }
    
    public async Task<someType> DoSomethingMethod(string param1, string param2, int param3){
        try{
            //Run business logic here
            CustomEventArgs args = new CustomEventArgs(param1, ...);
            SomethingHappenedEvent?.Invoke(this, args);
        } catch (Exception ex){
            throw
        }
    }
}
```

The DoSomethingMethod creates an instance of the CustomEventArgs class and then tries to invoke (trigger) the event in the following line, passing it the object reference (this) and the CustomEventArgs object. Finally, the following code shows the class that's supposed to handle the event.

```
public class EventMonitorClass{
    private HelperClass _helperClass;
    
    public EventMonitorClass(HelperClass helperClass){
        _helperClass = helperClass;
        _helperClass.SomethingHappenedEvent += _helperClass_SomethingHappenedEvent;
        //Other initialization code here
    }
    
    private void _helperClass_SomethingHappenedEvent(object sender, CustomEventArgs e){
        //Event handling code here
    }
}
```

I registered the event in this class' constructor and defined the event handler method, which has the same signature as the delegate type associated with the event. I followed the standard procedure  for adding events to an application, yet every time I run my code in Visual Studio I don't see the event firing or the event handler getting called. Is there something I am missing here? Any clues to point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

I tried creating a custom delegate type as well as using the EventHandler delegate type. I tried changing the async methods to run synchronously, using Task.Wait() and similar constructs.

Comment: So `HelperClass` should probably be a singleton service, which you inject into your controller? But then you could just define an interface, and a default implementation. With your one customer overriding that implementation to perform their emailing or whatever.  Though do you want to block the caller request while sending an email? Or should you queue those emails, in which case how will you log / handle any errors? ....

Comment: To be more precise, HelperClass does several things. It has a method that takes care of deserializing the JSON payload from the request received by the controller. It also has asynchronous methods that call other web API's using an HttpClient field. One particular reason why I want to know if you can use events with asynchronous code is because the HttpClient client class like the many other classes in the System.Net.Http namespace (i.e. HttpRequestMessage, HttpResponseMessage) work mostly with asynchronous methods.

Comment: IMHO it's safer to write a `BackgroundService` with a process queue, so you can catch and log exceptions in a single location. But that depends on how you want to handle failed emails.